# Unable to connect to mysql host from docker container

Tags: java, mysql, docker, intellij-idea

I'm running application from docker container, that attempts to connect with mysql host

mysql host is localhost
and my docker container running on localhost:8080

and here's my config.yml file

```
database:
  driverClass: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  # TODO: if running locally without k8s, change the service url to your localhost
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/locations?useSSL=false
  user: root
  password: root
  maxWaitForConnection: 1s
  validationQuery: "SELECT now()"
  validationQueryTimeout: 3s
  minSize: 8
  maxSize: 32
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
  evictionInterval: 10s
  minIdleTime: 1 minute
  checkConnectionOnBorrow: true
```

When i tried to access my app it always gives me the exception

```
ERROR [2018-02-08 18:16:56,508] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
! java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I've tried many solution over google :D, but nothing works for me!

my java connector version:

compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.9-rc'

Can anybody help!
Also i'm running on ubuntu,

When i tried to run my app from the IDE, it works well, but from docker container gives the exception!

Comment: tried, but not helping me

Comment: Bind your application listening port with IP `0.0.0.0` (in the container) and then try to access MySQL from the application container.

Answer (score 1):

If your mysql is running as a docker container, then you may need to link your docker container with your mysql container:

`docker run --link mysql_container_name:db your_application`

You can then modify your jdbc url to say `jdbc:mysql://db:3306/locations?useSSL=false`. This is because you have linked your two docker containers together, and established `db` as a hostname within docker that points to your mysql container.

If your mysql database is not running in a docker container but on your local machine, then it gets a bit more complicated. If you are not on a linux machine, then your Docker containers are technically running in a virtual machine for Docker. `localhost` from the container's perspective is, therefore, the docker virtual machine and not your physical machine where MySQL is running.

If this is the case, an easy fix would be to use your machine's network IP address instead of `localhost` in your jdbc URL. Supposing your machine's IP address is `192.168.0.10`:

`jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.10:3306/locations?useSSL=false`

Comment: Right, but still i'm not running my mysql as container, it's running as host through Apache server

Comment: The second part of my answer includes an alternative option if you are not running mysql in docker: Try substituting your IP address for localhost in your JDBC url.

Comment: But i'm running on ubuntu :D